# dynamic linq query options

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a form that I'm serializing into a json object that looks like this:

```
Fruit: Apple,
StrawberyParam: "test",
AppleParam: 1,
PeachParam: 3,
Car: Porsche
BugattiParam:3,
PorscheParam: "gas",
ToyotaParam: "go",
AnotherParam: "test1"
```

Basically, the user selects a fruit and a car and the parameters are described in the other properties.

I'm thinking of writing the different where clauses and concatenating them to create a string and then applying a .ToList to it like this:

```
StrawberryWhere = ....
AppleWhere = ....
PeachWhere = ....
PorscheWhere = ....
.....
```

And then writing this:

```
MyQuery = fromClause + switch based on Fruit and Car selected
          (ie. AppleWhere + PorscheWhere) + selectClause;
MyQuery.ToList();
```

Is this how it's done? I'm using linq-to-sql and I'm not very familiar with this framework so thank you for suggestions.

Comment: If you're using LinqToSql, what tables are you querying? Can you give a couple of sql-text examples of the queries you'd like to generate?

Comment: The where clauses look at 6 different tables depending on the Car and Fruit.

Comment: You should learn more about linq-to-sql, so you can avoid obvious mistakes in your question, such as using + to add to a query, or dynamically choosing the query source when you could conditionally choose the query source. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx  You should not look at Dynamic Linq until you understand LinqToSql out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use strings, you would do something like this:

```
Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> appleWhere = x => x.Fruit == Fruits.Apple;
Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> porscheWhere = x => x.Car == Cars.Porsche;
// ...

var result = jsonObjects.Where(appleWhere).Where(porscheWhere).ToList();
```

Comment: Can't use Func<T, bool> with linq to sql.

Comment: It should work with Expressions though... I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Dynamic LINQ:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx